# How to connect blog posts to social media streams?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, social-networking

I want to connect a blog, so that every post made results in a corresponding post (tweet, status update, …) in diverse registered social media streams.

Is there a gem that abstracts away the particularities of the different social media services and would allow me to do this with some configuration only?

The blog is done in RoR 3, so obviously, I’d prefer a gem, but if there is a component in javascript that does this, or a web service, that would be ok as well.

Any ideas?